# TPU keras regression very slow compared to GPU/CPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I'm doing a regression on a column in a dataframe. When I use a CPU, each epoch is ~95 seconds, when using a GPU it's ~45 seconds, but when using a TPU it's over **8 mins** for each epoch.

I basically initialized the tpu, wrapped my model definition and compile into a TPU distribution strategy.

I * think * the problem is in my dataset. I've seen tutorials were the data is put into tensors (for my gpu/cpu performance I was sending the dataframe (X_train and y_train in my code below). I tried to both dataframe and tensor's, both are order of magnitude worst than a cpu.  I'm sure this is a user error I just can't see my mistake.

Here's my code:

```
#setup tpu 

import os
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
# This is the TPU initialization code that has to be at the beginning.
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))
tpu_strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)


def KerasRegression(FullDF, variableToPredict):
  
  df_train1 = FullDF[FullDF[variableToPredict].notna()].copy() #lets make train data not have na for variable we are trying to predict

  X_train = df_train1.drop(variableToPredict, axis=1)
  y_train = df_train1[variableToPredict].copy()
  x_train_shape = X_train.shape[1]

  dateset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).batch(batch_size=100).prefetch(buffer_size=5000)
  
  activationLayer = 'relu'

  with tpu_strategy.scope():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(x_train_shape, activation=activationLayer, input_dim=x_train_shape))
    model.add(Dense(x_train_shape, activation=activationLayer))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'],
                  experimental_steps_per_execution = 50)
  model.fit(dateset, epochs=100) 
  # model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100) 
  return model
```

Also if it helps the shape of my testing data is:

```
(590543, 209)
```

Any feedback is welcomed!

Comment: What is a length of dataset ? Length matter for TPU. From my experience - TPU perfoms bad on small datasets. Try to create huge dataset of random numbers and compare TPU vs GPU

Comment: Hi @Andrey - the shape is (590543, 209) - when I save the DF as a CSV it's about 650 mb

Comment: Hi @Lostsoul ! I played with random input on colab TPU. Every epoch took 33 sec. But it could be significantly improved by increasing batch size: I tried 1024 and got 5 sec per epoch. See here - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10oK6tgYO8oCl0KyZWkbUCxhWrTa8XJ7A#scrollTo=0SKPugANh9mi

Comment: Please try this link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10oK6tgYO8oCl0KyZWkbUCxhWrTa8XJ7A?usp=sharing

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for this. I could be wrong, but I think what the batch flag does is divide the data over that # of batches. When I tried about 45 batches I got 11811 rows, which took about 69 seconds to process. My GPU version my code can do it in 45 seconds. I think this is performing slower still? creating more batches, shrinks the data which makes the epochs go faster but I do not think is a sign of speed up.

Comment: Batch parameter means a size of one batch - not number of batches. The more batch size - the faster training on TPU. Small batches could be trained faster on GPU/CPU

Comment: so if the data is 100 rows..a batch size of 100 means 100 rows in 1 batch? whereas a batch size of 50 is 2 batches?

Comment: yes, you are right. And as far as I remember - it is recommended to set batch size divisible by 8 (or better by 128)

Comment: @Andrey omg, I was hoping you were wrong because I felt the TPU was going too fast with higher batch sizes that it must have only processed a small subset of my data! I spent the last 2 days trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.  Thank you so much for your help with my embarrassing mistake.

Comment: You are welcome